# "semi transparent", what is used in between?

Tags: orthography

How do you write the word semi transparent (meaning partially transparent)?

1. semitransparent
2. semi-transparent
3. semi transparent

I found each of them on the Internet and none of them in my English dictionary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [British National Corpus](http://www.natcorp.ox.ac.uk/) has 4 mentions of *semitransparent*, and none of either *semi-transparent* or *semi transparent*.

Wiktionary has an entry for [*semitransparent*](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/semitransparent), but not for *semi-transparent*. Merriam-Webster has an entry for [*semitransparent*](http://mw4.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/semitransparent) and says that the first known use was in 1731.

(Google seems to be rather unreliable here: searching for "semi transparent" matches *semitransparent* and *semi-transparent*, and vice versa.)

Comment: I tried to find the corresponding numbers from the Corpus of Contemporary American English, but got heartily tired of fighting with the interface and gave up.

Answer (score 3):

The *American Heritage Dictionary Fourth Edition* includes “semitransparent”.

“semi-”, in this case, is being used a prefix rather than a word. Because of this, I would not use “semi transparent”.

Regarding “semi-transparent”, my understanding is that the hyphen tends to be dropped and the word elements combined to form a derivative word according to how common the combination is. Therefore, if I had not been able to locate it in the dictionary, then I would likely have used the hyphenated prefix.

Answer (score 3):

I know "semi-transparent" and "semitransparent" are both used, but normally I see it written as "translucent". Anyway, unless if you're writing a formal document, it doesn't matter because everyone will get it, and I wouldn't look at a dictionary because language changes faster than dictionary publications.

Comment: “translucent” indicates distortion of the partially-blocked image, while “semitransparent” does not.

Comment: @Jeffrey: I've never heard that meaning of "translucent" and my online dictionary search finds no such meaning.  To me, translucent means "light goes through".  Do you have a source for your definition? In my English Translucent and Semitransparent are synonyms.

Comment: The American Heritage Dictionary says "1. Transmitting light but causing sufficient diffusion to prevent perception of distinct images." I originally put "connotes" on my comment, but after I read the definition, I changed it to "indicates".

Comment: @Jeffrey: I'd say "diffusion" is different than "distortion"

Comment: @Mr. Shiny and New - I would say that distortion includes diffusion. And though you may ding me for lack of specificity in my comment, it is clear that “translucent” is not the same as “semi-transparent”.

Comment: Distortion and diffusion are different words with different meanings. When talking about light and reflection, distortion most of the times includes diffusion, but diffusion doesn't imply distortion at all. Semi-transparent is most likely to imply diffusion than distortion as you see a whiter/pale object and not a deformed one (a dog between semitransparent glass would still look like a dog, a paler one, but still a dog). Translucent doesn't mean distortion at all.