# Difference between "transparent" and "translucent"

Tags: single-word-requests

What's the difference between *transparent* and *translucent*? I am trying to describe [this record pressing](http://78.46.76.238/pix/20110404/180649108392.jpg).

Comment: There's some discussion of the difference between transparent and translucent in this answer, but it isn't conclusive http://english.stackexchange.com/a/4308/4915

Comment: remark that transparent can be used more abstractly (as in, "a transparent idea"), but it would be more awkward to do the same with translucent.

Comment: What does the dictionary tell you? What's unclear about what it says?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

These are both Latin words, and the etymologies help here.

- *trans* simply means *through*
- *lūceō* simply means *to shine*

So *translucent* means 'shining through' -- i.e, light passes through, though nothing is said about an image.

- *pāreō* means *to look, seem or appear; to think (of); to sound (like)*

So *transparent* clearly refers to identifiable images, most likely visual (hence implying light), but also any sensory percept involving a mental image, as in *a transparent lie.*

Since *transparent* usually entails light passing through a substance, *translucent* has become specialized in its sense to entail light passing, but no image.

Answer (score 19):

Generally **transparent** means light goes through undisturbed and so makes an image, while **translucent** allows light through but not an image (e.g. frosted glass).

Answer (score 9):

Something that is **transparent** lets all light through without distorting the image -- it is as if the transparent object were not even there, visually speaking.  Something that is **translucent** lets some but not all light through.  Something that is **opaque** lets no light through.

Something that is translucent could be anywhere between transparent and opaque; that's a pretty broad range.

[Possibly more than you wanted to know on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transparency_and_translucency) can be found at Wikipedia.

Answer (score 1):

To make it easier to differentiate, translucent = semi transparent.

Answer (score -1):

Technically speaking translucent is semi-transparent. As simple as that. But translucent is only a technical term while transparent may be used figuratively i.e. something which is evident, clearly seen or understood. "Transparent policy, accounting etc."