# Difference between "translucency" and "transparency"

Tags: differences

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between “transparent” and “translucent”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/56639/difference-between-transparent-and-translucent)

Can some one tell me what is the difference between the words "translucency" and  "transparency" (maybe in context)? Or they are absolute synonymous and there is no difference of using. 
Thank you!

Comment: Which [online] dictionaries have you consulted and what did you find unclear? (Oops, pun not intended) Merriam-Webster shows there is a difference: [transparent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/transparent) | [translucent](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/translucent)

Comment: It is unclear what those words mean, but a native speaker would be likely to produce either; neverthless, the two words are not interchangeable. If I should guess at the differences I would be necessary to see the wider context to be sure.